# Count only where certain fields are unique? (Multiple GROUP BYs)

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

So I have a query which will count how many records there are for each date in the past 3 days, from my last question with the help of others I was able to come up with the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dailyCount
FROM highscores
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

The query does the following, for the past 30 days, it will get how many records there are on each individual day and that will be returned as `dailyCount`.

However what I want to do now is get it so that `dailyCount` will only count fields where `username` has not been counted before.

I have tried the following (adding `username` to the GROUP BYs):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dailyCount
FROM highscores
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(date), username
```

However that did not give the expected result.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to get out. how many users got a new highscore within the last 3 days?

Comment: @MarcB added an explanation to the question, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT username)` instead of `username` in the `GROUP BY`? Or should it not count in other days as well?

Comment: @Wrikken That worked I believe, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Credits to [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575455/count-only-where-certain-fields-are-unique-multiple-group-bys/16575659#comment23818566_16575455)*

The following worked:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS dailyCount
FROM highscores
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Comment: You can replace the `WHERE` condition with `WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` if you want it to use an index on `(date)`.